# Getting Node Object through Ajax call in Spring

Tags: java, ajax, spring, jquery, xml-parsing

I am using Spring with Ajax. Through Ajax I am calling a controller method in which I am loading an xml file and parsing it. I want to pass the parsed node (Object) to the html page as a response to the Ajax call.

This is my Ajax Call

```
$.ajax({
        url: "query1",
        type: "POST",
        //dataType: "xml",
        success: function(data) {
            alert("in jax response");
            alert("DATA" + data);
          // parseXml(data);
        }
    });
```

This is my Controller method

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/query1", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody Node executeQuery1(ModelMap model) throws ParserConfigurationException, SAXException,IOException, XPathExpressionException {
        // Standard of reading a XML file
          DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
          factory.setNamespaceAware(true);
          DocumentBuilder builder;
          Document doc = null;
          XPathExpression expr = null;
          builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
          String filepath = "C:\\test.xml";
          System.out.println("PATH: " + filepath);
          doc = builder.parse(filepath);

          // Create a XPathFactory
          XPathFactory xFactory = XPathFactory.newInstance();

          // Create a XPath object
          XPath xpath = xFactory.newXPath();

        // Compile the XPath expression
          expr = xpath.compile("//person[@id=1]");
          // Run the query and get a nodeset
          Object result = expr.evaluate(doc, XPathConstants.NODE);

          // Cast the result to a DOM NodeList
          Node personNode = (Node) result;
          model.addAttribute("xmlnode", personNode);
          System.out.println("model set. going to return");
         return personNode;

    }
```

If I return a string instead of the Node, I get the alert popup. But on returning the Node Object it fails.

Also I would like to parse this Node further in Javascript. So please let me know the best way to do it. Should I convert the Node to XML String and return the XML String?

Answer (score 0):

You can use JSON format for your objects being returned. For example with [Jackson JSON API](http://jackson.codehaus.org/), you can convert your object into a JSON format and return as a String. Alternatively, if you would like to use XML, convert your Node object into an XML representation and return as a String. With XML as a String you need to parse it in AJAX code accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

(My previous version assumed you were passing the XML from the client to the server).

You can't pass a DOM node as-is.  It won't serialize using the `toString` method.

To pass a DOM subtree you need to unparse it back to XML.  The Java Tutorial page on ["Writing Out a DOM as an XML File"](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxp/xslt/writingDom.html) has an example that does pretty much what you are trying to do.  Look for the heading "Writing Out a Subtree of the DOM".  (The only difference is that your code uses XPath rather than the DOM API to locate the node you want.)

Alternatively, you could "hand serialize" your Node by traversing the DOM tree, extracting the content into new (non-DOM) objects and then serializing those ... somehow.  For instance, you could construct JSONObject/JSONArray instances and then serialize as JSON.  What you get at the client side won't be XML.  (That could be a good thing.)

Comment: The simple and obvious approach is to simply pass the XML to the server in its original form   -- you mean passing the XML to client in original form ?? IF yes then that cannot be done since by doing that the entire xml can be viewed at client side. Security contraints are there hence parsing of XML at server side is needed.